# Can we access Sharepoint 2010 content from sharepoint 2013? If yes, how to achieve it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can we access Sharepoint 2010 content from sharepoint 2013? If yes, how to achieve it. I am having a sharepoint 2010 site with some list and document libraries. Can we get the content from sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Could you please elaborate or rephrase your question? It is unclear to me what your goal is.

Comment: @TempaC He probably wants to move documents from one site to another, that's what I assumed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the list export and import function.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-lists-HA001154562.aspx

Comment: Hi! Please try to add the important parts from your link to your answer. As it stands now, your answer will not be muche help if the link is broken / down :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write an application using Microsoft.SharePoint dlls or even one with CSOM that downloads files from a specific list and uploads them to another in a completely different site.

Look at this question for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

> ```
>   String fileToUpload = @"C:\YourFile.txt"; 
>         String sharePointSite = "http://yoursite.com/sites/Research/"; 
>         String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents"; 
>
>         using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite)) 
>         { 
>             using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb()) 
>             { 
>                 if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload)) 
>                     throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);                     
>
>                 SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName]; 
>
>                 // Prepare to upload 
>                 Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true; 
>                 String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload); 
>                 FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload); 
>
>                 // Upload document 
>                 SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles); 
>
>                 // Commit  
>                 myLibrary.Update(); 
>             } 
>         }
> ```

You can also do as Pieter suggested and follow these instructions:

> **Create a list template based on the list:**
>
> 1. On the top link bar, click Documents and Lists.
> 2. On the Documents and Lists page, click the list that you want to
>      copy.
> 3. On the page that displays the list, click Modify settings and columns.
> 4. On the Customize List_Name page, under General Settings, click Save list as template.
> 5. In the File Name box, type the file name to use for the template file.
> 6. In the Template Title box, type the title that you want to use for the template in the list template gallery.
> 7. In the Template Description box, type a description for the template.
> 8. Select the Include content check box.
> 9. Click OK.
> 10. On the Operation Completed Successfully page, click OK.
>
> **If your sites are not in the same site collection, export the list template from the source site:**
>
> On the top level site of the site collection containing the list that
>   you want to copy, click Site Settings. In the Administration section,
>   click Go to Site Administration. In the Site Collection Galleries
>   section, click Manage list template gallery. On the List Template
>   Gallery page, click the list template that you want to export. In the
>   File Download dialog box, click Save. In the Save As dialog box,
>   navigate to the network location where you want to save the list
>   template file, and then click Save. In the Download Complete dialog,
>   click Close.
>
> **If your sites are not in the same site collection, import
>   the list template to the destination site:**
>
> On the top level site of the site collection that contains the source
>   site, click Site Settings. In the Administration section, click Go to
>   Site Administration. In the Site Collection Galleries section, click
>   Manage list template gallery. Click Upload template. In the Name box,
>   type of the full path to the network location of the list template
>   file, or click Browse, locate the file by using the Choose file dialog
>   box, and then click Open. Click Save and close.
>
> **Create the copy of the list:**
>
> In the destination Web site, in the top link bar, click Create. On the
>   Create page, click the list template that you created to copy the
>   list. On the New List page, in the Name box, specify the copied list's
>   name and, optionally, in the Description box, type a description of
>   the list. Click Create.
>
> **Delete the list template (optional):**
>
> After you use the list template that you imported to create a copy of
>   the list, you can delete the list template from the site collection
>   list template gallery.
>
> On the top level site of the site collection that contains the source
>   site, click Site Settings. In the Administration section, click Go to
>   Site Administration. In the Site Collection Galleries section, click
>   Manage list template gallery. On the List Template Gallery page, find
>   the list template that you want to delete and click Edit Properties
>   Edit Document Properties. Click Delete, and then click OK when
>   prompted. To move a list, delete the original list.
>
> **If you want to move the list to the destination site, you can delete
>   the list from the source site:**
>
> On the source site, on the top link bar, click Documents and Lists.
>   Click the name of the list you want to delete. On the page that
>   displays the list or library, click Modify settings and columns. Under
>   General Settings, click Delete this list.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access SharePoint 2010 content from SharePoint 2013 is to use search. SharePoint 2013 search can crawl previous SharePoint versions and thus expose the content to your users in the new portal.

c.f. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219577.aspx#Section3